# MySQL many-to-many relationship with FOREIGN KEYS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship in my MySQL database. I have three tables:
`Films`,  `Genres` and `Films_Genres`. I am using the following code to set them up:

```
CREATE TABLE Films
(  
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),   
    Title VARCHAR(255)
),  

CREATE TABLE Genres
(  
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    PRIMARY KEY(id),  
    Name VARCHAR(255)
),

CREATE TABLE Films_Genres
(
    film_id INT NOT NULL,  
    genre_id INT NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (film_id, genre_id),  
    FOREIGN KEY (film_id) REFERENCES Films(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
    FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES Genres(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

However, when I try to insert some values into the tables with:

```
INSERT INTO Films (Title) VALUES ('$title')
INSERT INTO Genres (Name) VALUES ('$genre')
```

I can see the new Film in `Films` table and the new Genre in `Genres` table but
the `Films_Genres` table doesn't update - there are no new rows (I'm checking through phpMyAdmin).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Paste the PHP code, or we can't help. Have you verified `$title` and `$genre` exist? Etc..

Comment: I can show the results from Films and Genres - they work. The only problem is that the Films_Genres table doesnt add up any rows. PHP seems fine. Im using mysqli_query($con, $sql) to execute the SQL code. Is the SQL correct though?

Comment: So I'm assuming the connection in `Films_Genres` missing is your question in concern. If that's the case, you'll need to relate those two records yourself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You won't see anything in `Films_Genres` table until you explicitly insert something in it.
Referential integrity through PK and FK is not for populating your tables for you.

Your MySql code for inserting a new record in `Films_Genres`, if it's a new film which correspond to a new genre, might look like

```sql
INSERT INTO Films (Title) VALUES ('Title1');
SET @film_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Genres (Name) VALUES ('Genre1');
SET @genre_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Films_Genres (film_id, genre_id) VALUES(@film_id, @genre_id);
```

*On php side to get a newly assigned id for an autoincremented field use [`$mysqli->insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).*

Now if you want to create a new film and assign it to multiple genres at once you can do

```sql
INSERT INTO Films (Title) VALUES ('Title2');
SET @film_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
-- if you get ids of genre from your UI just use them
INSERT INTO Films_Genres (film_id, genre_id) 
SELECT @film_id, id
  FROM Genres
 WHERE id IN (2, 3, 4);

INSERT INTO Films (Title) VALUES ('Title3');
SET @film_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
-- if you names of genres you can use them too
INSERT INTO Films_Genres (film_id, genre_id) 
SELECT @film_id, id
  FROM Genres
 WHERE Name IN ('Genre2', 'Genre4');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fca6a/3)** demo

Comment: Wow! I couldnt have expected a better anwser! Thanks a lot! I love stackoverflow :D

Comment: @Sharkz You're welcome :) See updated answer for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill the many-to-many table yourself mate, that's how mysql works, there's no automatic guess work performed here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should insert a row into the link table as well to 'link' a film and a genre you've just inserted.Mysql engine doesn't do that for you automatically(it simply doesn't know that those 2 records should be somehow related) - this is to be done on application side or manually

```
INSERT INTO Films_Genres (film_id,genre_id) VALUES (1,1)
```